# Select option in PHP not echoing back correctly

Tags: php, forms, selection

As a precursor, it is worth mentioning that I am new at PHP. I've spent roughly 3 hours working on what seems like it should be a simple fix.

Using PHP to echo back a form after choosing submit, my drop-down menu is only echoing back the first name, regardless of which one is selected.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="echo_form_email.php" method="GET">

<p>
<div id="cheddar">Cashier: <input id="cashier" name="cashier" type="text"></div> 
</p>

<P>
<div id="q">Did the cashier front the register?</div>
<div id="radio1"><input type="checkbox" name="front_register" value="Yes">Yes</div> 
<div id="radio2"><input type="checkbox" name="front_register" value="No">No</div> 
<div id="radio3"><input type="checkbox" name="front_register" value="N/A">N/A</div>
</p>

<p>
<div id="q">Genuinely greet customer with eye contact?</div>
<div id="radio1"><input type="checkbox" name="greets" value="Yes">Yes</div> 
<div id="radio2"><input type="checkbox" name="greets" value="No">No</div> 
</p>

<p>
<div id="q">Scan/unload B.O.B. (If no bagger)</div>
<div id="radio1"><input type="checkbox" name="scan_bob" value="Yes">Yes</div> 
<div id="radio2"><input type="checkbox" name="scan_bob" value="No">No</div> 
<div id="radio3"><input type="checkbox" name="scan_bob" value="N/A">N/A</div>
</p>

<p>
<div id="q">Carry conversation around product in basket or genuine conversation?</div>
<div id="radio1"><input type="checkbox" name="conversation" value="Yes">Yes</div> 
<div id="radio2"><input type="checkbox" name="conversation" value="No">No</div> 
<div id="radio3"><input type="checkbox" name="conversation" value="N/A">N/A</div>
</p>

<p>
<div id="q">Offer buddy bucks to parent at beginning of order?</div>
<div id="radio1"><input type="checkbox" name="buddy" value="Yes">Yes</div> 
<div id="radio2"><input type="checkbox" name="buddy" value="No">No</div> 
<div id="radio3"><input type="checkbox" name="buddy" value="N/A">N/A</div> 
</p>

<p>
<div id="q">Avoid side conversations?</div>
<div id="radio1"><input type="checkbox" name="side_conversation" value="Yes">Yes</div> 
<div id="radio2"><input type="checkbox" name="side_conversation" value="No">No</div> 
</p>

<p>
<div id="q">Point out and circle savings?</div>
<div id="radio1"><input type="checkbox" name="savings" value="Yes">Yes</div> 
<div id="radio2"><input type="checkbox" name="savings" value="No">No</div> 
<div id="radio3"><input type="checkbox" name="savings" value="N/A">N/A</div>
</p>

<p>
<div id="q">Offer carryout (if no bagger)?</div>
<div id="radio1"><input type="checkbox" name="carry_out" value="Yes">Yes</div> 
<div id="radio2"><input type="checkbox" name="carry_out" value="No">No</div> 
<div id="radio3"><input type="checkbox" name="carry_out" value="N/A">N/A</div>
</p>

<p>
<div id="q">Give a genuine "thank you"?</div>
<div id="radio1"><input type="checkbox" name="thanks" value="Yes">Yes</div> 
<div id="radio2"><input type="checkbox" name="thanks" value="No">No</div> 
</p>

<p>
<div id="cheddar">Digital Signature</div>
<div id="cheddar"><input type="tel" name="sign1" placeholder="Peoplesoft ID"></div>
</p>

<p>
<div id="auditingasm">ASM performing audit: <br />
<select name="asm">
<option value="John Doe">John Doe</option>
<option value="Jane Doe">Jane Doe</option>
<option value="Little Doe">Little Doe</option>
<option value="Big Doe">Big Doe</option>
</select>
</p>

<br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
<input id="reset" type="reset">
</form>
```

Using the above code, regardless of which option I choose before submitting, the echoed results will always come back as "John Doe."

Here is my PHP:

```
<?PHP
if (! empty($_GET['cashier'])){
   echo 'Cashier receiving audit: ' . $_GET['cashier'];
}
echo "<br />";
if (! empty($_GET['asm'])){
   echo 'ASM performing audit: ' . $_GET['asm'];
}
    echo "<br /><Br />";
if (! empty($_GET['front_register'])){
       echo 'Did cashier front the register? ' . $_GET['front_register'];
}
echo "<br />";
if (! empty($_GET['greets'])){
   echo 'Greet customer with eye contact? ' . $_GET['greets'];
}
    echo "<br />";
if (! empty($_GET['scan_bob'])){
echo 'Scan/Unload BOB (if no bagger) ' . $_GET['scan_bob'];
}
echo "<br />";
if (! empty($_GET['conversation'])){
   echo 'Conversation about groceries, or other genuine conversation? ' .             $_GET['conversation'];
}
echo "<br />";
if (! empty($_GET['buddy'])){
   echo 'Offer Buddy bucks to parent at beginning of order? ' . $_GET['buddy'];
}
echo "<br />";
if (! empty($_GET['side_conversation'])){
   echo 'No side conversations? ' . $_GET['side_conversation'];
}
echo "<br />";
if (! empty($_GET['savings'])){
   echo 'Cashier pointed to and circled savings? ' . $_GET['savings'];
}
echo "<br />";
if (! empty($_GET['carry_out'])){
   echo 'Offered carry out (if no bagger) ' . $_GET['carry_out'];
}
echo "<br />";
if (! empty($_GET['thanks'])){
   echo 'Genuine "thank you?" ' . $_GET['thanks'];
}
echo "<br /><Br />";
if (! empty($_GET['sign1'])){
   echo 'Digital Signature: ' . $_GET['sign1'];
}
?>
```

My thanks in advance

Comment: What's the form submit method? GET or POST?

Comment: You don't have a form tag :-D

Comment: Try using urlencode(the name here)

Comment: do you have form tag?

Comment: Death - I do, this is just over 200 lines of code for this form in HTML, I was just posting the relevant part.

Mark - Form method is "GET"

Comment: Option values need to be set as an array. For example: Your `<option name="person[]" value="John Doe">John Doe</option>` plus you'll need to modify your PHP to reflect the changes to echo the name, if that's your intention.

Comment: I suggest posting the full 200 lines

Comment: option values do NOT need to be set as an array

Comment: @Zak why not then, and how?

Comment: @Fred: Because a select will only return one value if multiple selections aren't allowed. The name attribute in the select tag is all you need :)

Comment: @Zak I think I got mixed up with `select`. Still needs the use of `[]` - I always get those two mixed up.

Comment: @TobiasKun I always get those two mixed up, as I mentioned to Zak, just above here.

Comment: @Fred: No problem at all. Dustin please show your whole form code. Or we can't help you.

Comment: Once I reformat for public viewing, I'll repost.

Comment: @DustinSiebert I tested your **"posted"** code and it worked fine (adding my own <form></form> of course). Your problem lay elsewhere.

Comment: Complete code now attached.

Comment: ALL the echos show john doe?

Comment: @DustinSiebert I tested your edited/added code, and everything checked out. So, I don't know what the problem could be at your end. (Using FF v22) Try clearing your cache/cookies, see what that gives. Unless you've got some DB stuff happening, it's hard to say what the reason could be. May be something in `.htaccess` or `php.ini`, who knows. Maybe you didn't upload the latest copies of all the codes? Those are the only possible scenarios I can come up with.

Comment: dishwasherwithprogrammingskill - you're my hero, my friend.  Turns out, that missing div tag was causing the error.  After adding it in, it worked flawlessly.

Thank you all.

Comment: A missing DIV. For crying outloud. Must be using (groan) IE. I'm gonna remember THAT one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your select statement seems to be syntactically correct. Try validating your form and check for output.

```
<select name="asm" onchange="return validate(this);">
    <option value="">Select Option</option>
    <option value="John Doe">John Doe</option>
    <option value="John Doe">John Doe</option>
    <option value="Jane Doe">Jane Doe</option>
    <option value="Little Doe">Little Doe</option>
    <option value="Big Doe">Big Doe</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(obj){
   alert (obj.value);
   return false;
}
</script>
```

This will alert you with the value that was selected without passing the form to the next page for testing.

And you forgot to close the div tag for the select statement.