# PHP: Emailing echo results

Tags: php

I'm on the homestretch of a project I have been working on for about 2 weeks. My HTML form is created and fully, and functionally, compatible with the PHP.  Currently, after submitting the form it echo's the results back. At this point, I don't know where to go next.

I would like to be able to take the information from that page, and add a numerical digital signature (much like a PIN) and submit the final results to an email using PHP.

I can do the two separately. IE - I can create a form to echo the results, and I can create a form that immediately e-mails the results, but I don't understand how to do them in conjunction with each other.

How can I submit the form's echo results as an e-mail, while adding a digital signature?

(Since I offer no code, as I'm very new to PHP, I don't expect anyone to -do- this for me, but I'm struggling to find relevant information via google searches, so even pointing me in the right direction would be incredibly helpful.)

Thanks

and now I know better. All code:

## HTML

```
<form action="echo_form_email.php" method="GET">

<p>
<div id="cheddar">Cashier: <input id="cashier" name="cashier" type="text"></div> 
</p>

<P>
<div id="q">Did the cashier front the register?</div>
<div id="radio1"><input type="checkbox" name="front_register" value="Yes">Yes</div> 
    <div id="radio2"><input type="checkbox" name="front_register" value="No">No</div> 
<div id="radio3"><input type="checkbox" name="front_register" value="N/A">N/A</div>
</p>

<p>
<div id="q">Genuinely greet customer with eye contact?</div>
<div id="radio1"><input type="checkbox" name="greets" value="Yes">Yes</div> 
<div id="radio2"><input type="checkbox" name="greets" value="No">No</div> 
</p>

<p>
<div id="q">Scan/unload B.O.B. (If no bagger)</div>
<div id="radio1"><input type="checkbox" name="scan_bob" value="Yes">Yes</div> 
<div id="radio2"><input type="checkbox" name="scan_bob" value="No">No</div> 
<div id="radio3"><input type="checkbox" name="scan_bob" value="N/A">N/A</div>
</p>

<p>
<div id="q">Carry conversation around product in basket or genuine conversation?</div>
<div id="radio1"><input type="checkbox" name="conversation" value="Yes">Yes</div> 
<div id="radio2"><input type="checkbox" name="conversation" value="No">No</div> 
<div id="radio3"><input type="checkbox" name="conversation" value="N/A">N/A</div>
</p>

<p>
<div id="q">Offer buddy bucks to parent at beginning of order?</div>
<div id="radio1"><input type="checkbox" name="buddy" value="Yes">Yes</div> 
<div id="radio2"><input type="checkbox" name="buddy" value="No">No</div> 
<div id="radio3"><input type="checkbox" name="buddy" value="N/A">N/A</div> 
</p>

<p>
<div id="q">Avoid side conversations?</div>
<div id="radio1"><input type="checkbox" name="side_conversation" value="Yes">Yes</div> 
<div id="radio2"><input type="checkbox" name="side_conversation" value="No">No</div> 
</p>

<p>
<div id="q">Point out and circle savings?</div>
<div id="radio1"><input type="checkbox" name="savings" value="Yes">Yes</div> 
<div id="radio2"><input type="checkbox" name="savings" value="No">No</div> 
<div id="radio3"><input type="checkbox" name="savings" value="N/A">N/A</div>
</p>

<p>
<div id="q">Offer carryout (if no bagger)?</div>
<div id="radio1"><input type="checkbox" name="carry_out" value="Yes">Yes</div> 
<div id="radio2"><input type="checkbox" name="carry_out" value="No">No</div> 
<div id="radio3"><input type="checkbox" name="carry_out" value="N/A">N/A</div>
</p>

<p>
<div id="q">Give a genuine "thank you"?</div>
<div id="radio1"><input type="checkbox" name="thanks" value="Yes">Yes</div> 
<div id="radio2"><input type="checkbox" name="thanks" value="No">No</div> 
</p>

<p>
<div id="cheddar">Digital Signature</div>
<div id="cheddar"><input type="tel" name="sign1" placeholder="Peoplesoft ID"></div>
</p>

<p>
<div id="auditingasm">ASM performing audit: <br />
<select name="asm">
<option value="John Doe">John Doe</option>
<option value="Jane Doe">Jane Doe</option>
<option value="Little Doe">Little Doe</option>
<option value="Big Doe">Big Doe</option>
</select></div>
</p>

<br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
<input id="reset" type="reset">
</form>
```

### PHP Form echo

```
<?PHP
if (! empty($_GET['cashier'])){
   echo 'Cashier receiving audit: ' . $_GET['cashier'];
}
echo "<br />";
if (! empty($_GET['asm'])){
   echo 'ASM performing audit: ' . $_GET['asm'];
}
echo "<br /><Br />";
if (! empty($_GET['front_register'])){
   echo 'Did cashier front the register? ' . $_GET['front_register'];
}
echo "<br />";
if (! empty($_GET['greets'])){
   echo 'Greet customer with eye contact? ' . $_GET['greets'];
}
echo "<br />";
if (! empty($_GET['scan_bob'])){
   echo 'Scan/Unload BOB (if no bagger) ' . $_GET['scan_bob'];
}
echo "<br />";
if (! empty($_GET['conversation'])){
   echo 'Conversation about groceries, or other genuine conversation? ' .     $_GET['conversation'];
}
echo "<br />";
if (! empty($_GET['buddy'])){
   echo 'Offer Buddy bucks to parent at beginning of order? ' . $_GET['buddy'];
}
echo "<br />";
if (! empty($_GET['side_conversation'])){
   echo 'No side conversations? ' . $_GET['side_conversation'];
}
echo "<br />";
if (! empty($_GET['savings'])){
   echo 'Cashier pointed to and circled savings? ' . $_GET['savings'];
}
echo "<br />";
if (! empty($_GET['carry_out'])){
   echo 'Offered carry out (if no bagger) ' . $_GET['carry_out'];
}
echo "<br />";
if (! empty($_GET['thanks'])){
   echo 'Genuine "thank you?" ' . $_GET['thanks'];
}
echo "<br /><Br />";
if (! empty($_GET['sign1'])){
   echo 'Digital Signature: ' . $_GET['sign1'];
}
?>
```

### PHP Form Email

This is the original php attached to the form that e-mailed to the correct address to make the form printable. The code prior to this one is the PHP for echo, as @Death saw posted in another forum from earlier today.

```
<?
//---------------
// Cashier Audit
//---------------
$msg .= "Cashier being audited: ".$_POST["cashier"]."";
$msg .= "\n\nFront the register? $front_register\n";
$msg .= "Greet customer with eye contact? $greets\n";
$msg .= "Scan/Unload BOB (if no bagger) $scan_bob\n";
$msg .= "Conversation about groceries, or other genuine conversation? $conversation\n";
$msg .= "Offer Buddy bucks to parent at beginning of order? $buddy\n";
$msg .= "No Side Conversations? $side_conversation\n";
$msg .= "Cashier pointed to and circled savings? $savings\n";
$msg .= "Offered carry out (if no bagger)? $carry_out\n";
$msg .= "Genuine Thank You? $thanks\n\n";
$msg .= "**************************************************************\n";
$msg .= "\n\n\nCashier signature:__________________________";
$msg .= "\n                             $cashier";
$msg .= "\n\n\n\n\nASM signature:__________________________";
$msg .= "\n                         $asm";

//-----------------
// Signature Lines
//-----------------
.= $checkbox=$_POST['checkbox'];
.= $asm = $_POST['asm'];

$to = "email@address.com";
$from = "other@email.com";
$subject = "Service Audit";
$mailheaders = "From: \"$asm\" <$from> . \n";
//$mailheaders .= "Reply-To: $from\n\n";

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders);

?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to send verification mail in PHP on a registration form?

Comment: all good S.O questions have code

Comment: "Talk is cheap. Show me the code" -Linus Torvalds

Comment: well maybe look into output buffering. `ob_` funtions

Comment: @Markasoftware I think he's linus not linux :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds

Comment: he should change his name like **kim dotcom**

Comment: sorry, typo. I meant Linus

Comment: A script can contain different code, i.e. a `echo $results;` and a `mail($results);` consecutively after each other.

Comment: @Dustin There is no **Know it all** among us, so put some code here!

Comment: @Death It's probably [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18193647/1415724)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a HTML form and would like to:

1. Audit a Staff Member on a HTML/PHP Form (`audit.php`)
2. Post the Results of that Audit to another PHP Page/Form (`audit_confirm.php`)
3. The employee enters their ID on `audit_confirm.php` and then someone clicks 'Submit'
4. The information is sent as Email

**Audit Form [audit.php]**

Your first page/form posts data to the confirmation page, so change the action attribute of the form tag to post to `audit_confirm.php` i.e.

```
<form action="audit_confirm.php" method="post">
<!-- all your existing form data-->
</form>
```

**Audit Confirmation Form [audit_confirm.php]**

On `audit_confirm.php` you will create logic that:

1. Displays the Results of the Audit
2. Provide a confirmation form containing a text box that enables the Employee to enter their ID
3. Post this information to the same page and capture POST data (a hidden form element can be used to segment the form logic flow)
4. Send email with audit data
5. Redirect to your `audit.php` page so you can perform another audit

Replace what you have now called `PHP Form Echo` with this:

```
<?php

    switch(true)
    {
        case ($_POST['employee_id_confirm'] == true):

            //---------------
            // Cashier Audit
            //---------------
            $msg .= "Cashier being audited: ".$_POST['cashier']."";
            $msg .= "\n\nFront the register? ".$_POST['front_register']."\n";
            $msg .= "Greet customer with eye contact? ".$_POST['greets']."\n";
            $msg .= "Scan/Unload BOB (if no bagger) ".$_POST['scan_bob']."\n";
            $msg .= "Conversation about groceries, or other genuine conversation? ".$_POST['conversation']."\n";
            $msg .= "Offer Buddy bucks to parent at beginning of order? ".$_POST['buddy']."\n";
            $msg .= "No Side Conversations? ".$_POST['side_conversation']."\n";
            $msg .= "Cashier pointed to and circled savings? ".$_POST['savings']."\n";
            $msg .= "Offered carry out (if no bagger)? ".$_POST['carry_out']."\n";
            $msg .= "Genuine Thank You? ".$_POST['thanks']."\n\n";
            $msg .= "**************************************************************\n\n\n\n\n";
            $msg .= "Cashier signature:        ".$signature."\n";
            $msg .= "                     _______________________________";
            $msg .= "\n                     $cashier";
            $msg .= "\n\n\n\n\n";
            $msg .= "ASM signature:            ".$asm."\n";
            $msg .= "                     ________________________________";
            $msg .= "\n                         $asm";

            $to = "email@address.com";
            $from = "other@email.com";
            $subject = "Service Audit";
            $mailheaders = "From: \"".$asm."\" <".$from.">\r\n".
            "Reply-To: noreply@yourdomain.com\r\n".
            "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion();
            mail($to, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders);

            //redirect to audit.php
            header("Location:audit.php");
            exit();
            break;
    }

    //form data from audit.php
    $get_data_meta_arr = array(
        'cashier' => 'Cashier receiving audit:',
        'asm' => 'ASM performing audit:',
        'front_register' => 'Did cashier front the register?',
        'greets' => 'Greet customer with eye contact?',
        'scan_bob' => 'Scan/Unload BOB (if no bagger)',
        'conversation' => 'Conversation about groceries, or other genuine conversation?',
        'buddy' => 'Offer Buddy bucks to parent at beginning of order?',
        'side_conversation' => 'No side conversations?',
        'savings' => 'Cashier pointed to and circled savings?',
        'carry_out' => 'Offered carry out (if no bagger)',
        'thanks' => 'Genuine "thank you?"'  
    );

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Info Confirm</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="view-info">
        <h2>Audit Confirmation</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="form-confirm">
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
            <div class="field-hidden">
                <input type="hidden" name="employee_id_confirm" value="true">                    
            </div>
            <div class="echo">
                <?php
                foreach($get_data_meta_arr as $key => $value)
                {
                    $audit_question_str = $value;           //the audit question
                    $audit_result_str = $_GET[$key];        //the audit result              
                ?>
                <p><?php echo $audit_question_str.': '.$audit_result_str; ?></p>
                <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $audit_result_str; ?>">
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="employee_id">Employee ID</label>
                <input id="employee_id" type="text" name="signature" maxlength="40">
            </div>
            <div class="action">
                <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can do away with `PHP Form Email` as the email messaging feature is built-in to the above code.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Certainly on the right track, but 3 isn't quite right.

The easiest way I can explain this is that I'm an front end manager at a grocery store.  We perform audits on our employees periodically through the day, and record them.  The purpose of the echo page is to show them the results of the audit on the spot, and then entire their employee ID as confirmation that they'd seen it. 

I'm having trouble taking a form that echoes the data, adds another field of information, and then emails it.

Comment: @DustinSiebert You want to send the email after they've entered their employee ID?!

Comment: Exactly.

The idea is to echo the form to be able to perform the audit immediately on the spot - and then the employee can enter their employee ID number on that page as a "signature," and then it can be submitted.

Comment: @DustinSiebert Ok. Well that's what my updated answer does. You'll have to change your existing echo form and make it a single page with a form, see my edit

Comment: Wow, it looks awesome - but it's still not posting the data from the form.  In both the echo and the e-mail I'm receiving blank forms.  What am I missing?  I even renamed my files to audit.php and cashier_audit_confirm.php in order to follow directions easier.

Comment: Got it!
The line of code:
$audit_result_str = $_GET[$key];        //the audit result
should have read
$audit_result_str = $_POST[$key];        //the audit result

It now works flawlessly, truly appreciate your help Chuck.  It would literally have taken me weeks on my own. Thanks again.

Comment: @DustinSiebert You are welcome! I used `$_GET` because your original form had `method="get"` and not `method="post"`. Anyway, I'm glad you sorted it out. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to provide an "answer" without knowing the scope of the project, but you may find this function helpful in PHP:

`$output = file_get_contents($url);`

you can always add things to it afterwords, so if the above `$url` is the file that echoes results you could add something to the end like:

`$output .= $signature`

Then just email the $output as the body or what not